Why is there no jsonb_each in SQLite?
I have been working with SQLite’s JSON1 extension and have noticed that while there are jsonb_ variants for nearly all json_ functions, the jsonb_each function seems to be missing.
Here is the documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html
I have a jsonb column my_data that looks like this: [{"key1": "value1"}, {"key1": "value2"},...].
Let's say I want to find all key1 values using this query:
SELECT 
    j.value ->> 'key1' as key1
FROM 
    table1,
    json_each(table1.my_data) as j

Is j.value a json or a jsonb object here? Why is there no jsonb_each in SQLite? What is the most efficient way to access these values?

Are you sure it's missing? Looking at the SQLite repo I see commits that make json_each work with JSONB input. The json_ functions return JSONB but json_each returns a table, not JSONB. In any case, why isn't a valid question for a Q&A site, as it can only be answered by the SQLite team or by looking at their issues and roadmap.

Yes it returns a table but its value column contains values such as {"key1": "value1"} in this example. I am wondering if this column is using json text or jsonb blob.
I'll add "What is the most efficient way to access these values?" to this question. I am also asking "Is j.value a json or a jsonb object here?" Hopefully it's a valid question for this site.

Just try the query and look at the value. The real question is whether json_each and j.value ->> '$.key1' work at all. most efficient isn't a valid question. JSONB is used to reduce storage, not increase performance. Performance is affected by indexes, and SQLite has no JSON indexes. If you try to filter or aggregate using the contents of j you'll get slow performance.

The code works. "Most efficient" is a valid question. Maybe there is another way that I am not aware of.
JSONB is used to increase performance, please see the sqlite documentation: "The advantage of JSONB in SQLite is that it is smaller and faster than text JSON - potentially several times faster."

You misunderstood what that line means. Those "several times" aren't even 0.0001% of the overall query processing time. The real cost is disk IO. Databases ensure fast queries by using indexes to limit the number of rows they have to process and only load what's needed. And then, they aggressively cache data so they don't have to read it again. Scanning all table rows and processing every single value is several orders of magnitude slower than parsing a single value.

If the query you posted is all there is, it's the slowest possible query, no matter whether JSONB is used or not, because it has to read all rows, and parse all values to get the actual value.

Ok let's just just focus on this for now: new_value ->> 'key1 ' is faster if new_value is JSONB instead of JSON, correct?

But feel free to share a sql snippet to "Just try the query and look at the value.". I'd love to just do that
